# How can I extend the expiration date of a self-signed certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have this self-signed certificate. Is is possible for me to extend its expiration date using `openssl` without having to regenerate/resign all certificates it has signed? How?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww Thanks for input. Would you like me to close this question and ask elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but IMHO it should work.

You only need to generate new self-signed certificate with the same attributes (except some things like serial number, notAfter date etc.) and using the same private/public key pair..

- There is only KeyID in Authority Key Identifier of end entity certificates but public key of self-signed certificate stays the same.
- There could be subject and serial number in Authority Key Identifier of end entity certificates but you could resign self-signed certificate with the same serial number (IMHO bad practice). But if it isn't there you can/should use another serial number to distinguish these two self-signed certificates.
- There could be link to self-signed certificate in Authority Info Access of end entity certificates but you can always replace the file this link points at.